# Filter list function array java script

Tags: javascript, filter

I have an array below where I am trying filter for only numbers , however when I use this i still get the strings

```js
function filter_list(l) {
  arrs = []
  for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
    if (typeof l[i] == 'number');
    arrs.push(l[i]);
  }
  return arrs
}

console.log(
  filter_list([1,2,'a','b']), // [1,2]
  filter_list([1,'a','b',0,15]), // [1,0,15]
  filter_list([1,2,'aasf','1','123',123]), // [1,2,123]
)
```

However, when i change it to have i not be referencing the index i, when i do

```
filter_list([1,2,'a','b']) I  get [0, 1, 2, 3]  instead of [1,2]

function filter_list(l) {
arrs = []
  for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
    if (typeof i == 'number');
    arrs.push(i);
  }
return arrs
}
```

I'm wondering how it all flow to arrive at this.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you want? By looking at your first snippet, I think you are getting desired output

Comment: You're comparing `i` compare `l[i]`

Comment: i is just iterator, set in for loop. So you have just numbers from 0 to length - 1.

Comment: `i` is the index, which is from `0` to the length of the array that you provided. So they are always numbers. While written as `l[i]`, you're referring the `i`-th element of the array `l`, not the index `i` itself.

Comment: In your second snippet you are checking `typeof` of index, which will always be number, and you are pushing index only, so you will get index numbers in output

Comment: The semicolo(;) end of if condition is the reason. Semicolon ends the statement and then next line all i's value is pushed to arrs.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt is correct, but there should not be semicolon after if statement. Try this:

```js
function filter_list(l) {
arrs = []
  for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
    if (typeof l[i] === 'number'){
       arrs.push(l[i]);
    }
  }
  return arrs
}

console.log(filter_list([1,2,'a','b']))
console.log(JSON.stringify(filter_list([1,2,'a','b'])) === '[1,2]')

console.log(filter_list([1,'a','b',0,15]))
console.log(JSON.stringify(filter_list([1,'a','b',0,15])) == '[1,0,15]')

console.log(filter_list([1,2,'aasf','1','123',123]))
console.log(JSON.stringify(filter_list([1,2,'aasf','1','123',123])) === '[1,2,123]')
```

Note: you cannot directly compare arrays. You will have to either compare each value or the stringified version.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the for/of loop to get the value of each element

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 'a', 'b', 3, 4];
var out = [];

for(let el of arr){
  typeof el == 'number' ? out.push(el) : 0;
}

console.log(out);
```

I hope this helps

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 'a', 'b', 3, 4];

var filtered = arr.filter(x => typeof(x) == 'number');

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Thanks! Getting rid of the semi colon fixed it and makes sense it ends its.  The other ways are definitely good to understand also.

Comment: im glad for you! good luck on your proyects

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'typeof' and 'filter'. You are getting 0 as you are checking index.

```js
console.log(filter_list([1,2,'a','b'])) 
console.log(filter_list([1,'a','b',0,15]))
console.log(filter_list([1,2,'aasf','1','123',123]))



function filter_list(l) {
arrs = l.filter(item =>{
return typeof item ==='number';
});
return arrs
}
```